# 98 Ford Expedition. Anti theft-ignition problem (car not running)

Tags: ford, expedition

98 Ford Expedition. The car is flushing the theft lights, and is not starting. I been looking for information about this problem. It sounds that it is related to the PATS system that ford has on those car. However, there is not any good information about solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some instructions I found at [this site](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061112222454AAVYec8). They may or may not work. Your only other alternative, it appears, is to take the vehicle to the Ford dealership and have them reprogram the key(s) for you.

> It's going to take some time and patience, but this should help.
>
> Put the key in the ignition and turn it to the run position.
>
> Theft indicator proves out after 2 seconds and then flashes rapidly.
>
> After 15 minutes of flashing, The theft indicator will stop flashing.
>
> Within/Before a few minutes (5 I believe), after it has stopped, turn the key off and then back to run.
>
> Theft indicator proves out after 2 seconds and then flashes rapidly.
>
> After 15 minutes of flashing, The theft indicator will stop flashing.
>
> Within/Before a few minutes ( 4 on the second time), after it has stopped, turn the key off and then back to run.
>
> After 15 minutes of flashing, the theft indicator will stop.
>
> All original programmed keys will be erased and the key in the ignition is programmed.
>
> This is the procedure for programming a new key. Since you are programming an existing key, it may work on the first pass which is the procedure for programming a spare key. I hope this helps.